Little time-related bug in the chat
I just noticed a small glitch in the chat: the “x time ago” text does not seem to update correctly, resulting in a bit of a contradiction as the screenshot shows…
The comment by Pawel (posted 1 day ago) saying @mikeazo I just removed ´featured´ tag :) it’s not… was re-posted to our chat yesterday (1 day ago). 
Yet, the label to his message states “1 min ago”.

Surely, this doesn’t seem to be a bug that needs to be taken care of as soon as possible. Nevertheless, I wanted to leave a short note pointing to this (rather miniscule) bug. 
Not-A-Bug?
In case this is not a bug, it sure seems to be a bit confusing… which might hint at the fact this could be enhanced somehow. Related to that, I would like to echo what mikeazo already mentioned in his comment (as I don’t think I could have pin-pointed it that perfectly): I've always thought it strange that posting a link to a comment includes the "X min ago"

I'm not sure if this is a bug. This actually is a link to a comment on a meta-post (the chat system renders it fancy). Apparently mike posted this one 1 minute in chat after Pawel posted it originally.

I've always thought it strange that posting a link to a comment includes the "X min ago"

@SEJPM In that case, I should probably call it “confusing” instead of ”bug”… ;)

Quick jQuery fix: $('#chat .quote .relativetime').text(function () { return 'at ' + this.title }) :)
